# How does MercurialEclipse store passwords?

Tags: eclipse, security, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I'm using Eclipse with Mercurial Eclipse extension to connect to our cvs repositories. I know this extension doesn't use the Eclipse Secure Storage to store passwords so I would like to find out the actual way it uses to assess our system's security. I don't want plain text passwords hanging around my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is its not plain text but it is reversible. You can find details [here](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/src/1c42e5d4dcf710ec70323eaa61e4b2f21187f324/plugin/src/com/vectrace/MercurialEclipse/storage/HgRepositoryAuthCrypterFactory.java?at=default).

Comment: Thank you! Not what I hoped although.